# Is it safe to use rcu_dereference() inside local_bh_disable()/local_bh_enable()?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, lock-free, preemption, rcu

The `local_bh_disable`-function changes per-cpu (in case of x86 and recent kernels) `__preempt_count` or `current_thread_info()->preempt_count` otherwise.

Anyway that gives us a grace period, so we can assume that it will be redundant to do `rcu_read_lock()` inside `local_bh_disable()`. Indeed: [in earlier kernels we can see](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.17.14/source/net/core/dev.c#L1352) that `local_bh_disable()` is used for RCU and `rcu_dereference()` is called subsequently inside e.g. the `dev_queue_xmit`-function. Later `local_bh_disable()` was replaced with `rcu_read_lock_bh()`, which eventually became a little more complicated than just calling `local_bh_disable()`. Now it looks like this:

```
static inline void rcu_read_lock_bh(void)
{
   local_bh_disable();
   __acquire(RCU_BH);
   rcu_lock_acquire(&rcu_bh_lock_map);
   RCU_LOCKDEP_WARN(!rcu_is_watching(),"rcu_read_lock_bh() used illegally while idle");
}
```

Also there are enough articles describing the RCU APIs. [Here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt) we can see:

> Do you need to treat NMI handlers, hardirq handlers,
>       and code segments with preemption disabled (whether
>       via preempt_disable(), local_irq_save(), local_bh_disable(),
>       or some other mechanism) as if they were explicit RCU readers?
>       If so, RCU-sched is the only choice that will work for you.

This tells us to use the *RCU Sched API* in such cases, so `rcu_dereference_sched()` should help. From [this comprehensive table](https://lwn.net/Articles/609973/) we can realise that `rcu_dereference()` should be used only inside `rcu_read_lock`/`rcu_read_unlock`-markers.

However, it is not sufficiently clear. Can I use (in case of modern kernels) `rcu_dereference()` inside `local_bh_disable`/`local_bh_enable`-markers without misgiving of anything going wrong?

P.S. In my case, I can't change the code calling `local_bh_disable` to call e.g. `rcu_read_lock_bh`, so my code is runnung with bh already disabled. Also the usual RCU API is used. Thus, it is fraught with `rcu_read_lock` nested in `local_bh_disable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to mix-and-match APIs. If you need to use the RCU-bh API, you need to use [`rcu_dereference_bh`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17.5/source/include/linux/rcupdate.h#L554).

You can see that if you called `rcu_dereference_check` after `rcu_read_lock_bh`, it would correctly surmise it is [not called in a RCU read-side critical section](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17.5/source/kernel/rcu/update.c#L325); contrast the call to `lock_is_held(&rcu_lock_map)` with `rcu_lock_acquire(&rcu_bh_lock_map);` in your snippet above.

The kernel documentation for RCU [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt) (search for the section on "rcu_dereference()") gives an explicit example of correct usage; `rcu_dereference*` can only be called correctly after the corresponding `rcu_read_lock*` function has completed.

Comment: I've seen this documentation, but the first thing confused me was the usage in early kernels. And even more confused that the result of `rcu_read_lock*held` is used only for `RCU_LOCKDEP_WARN` inside `__rcu_dereference_check`... Does this mean that everything will work fine?

Comment: I should use the standard RCU API, so only the `rcu_dereference` is welcome. Also I obviously shouldn't go against the latest documentation. So if I'm already inside `local_bh_disable` I just have to frame `rcu_dereference` with `rcu_read_lock`/`rcu_read_unlock`-markers and such *"preemption disabling"*-nesting will not be shameful?

Comment: If you need to use RCU with preemption disabled (i.e. inside `local_bh_disable`) you can only use RCU-bh, there is no other alternative which will work correctly.

Comment: So you mean that the following sequence is incorrect? `local_bh_disable()`->`rcu_read_lock()`->`rcu_dereference()`->`rcu_read_unlock()`->`local_bh_enable()`

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17.5/source/include/linux/rcupdate.h#L698), I can assume that the above sequence is still correct, isn't it?

Comment: Perhaps it happened to work correctly in a certain kernel version. Generally - and currently - I can't make that statement; see for instance the defs of ` rcu_read_lock*_held`. It seems to me the comment is out of date.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Summing up, we can say that doing `local_bh_disable()`->`rcu_dereference()`->`local_bh_enable()` is incorrect usage nowdays. And [this above sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236711/is-it-safe-to-use-rcu-dereference-inside-local-bh-disable-local-bh-enable/51244024?noredirect=1#comment89470747_51244024) is presumably correct based on comments in kernel source, but clarification is needed.